# Rails 3 f.select not showing current value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

```
<%= f.select :phase_names, options_for_select(["RFP Stage", "Pre Contract", "Awarded", "Unsuccessful", "Completed"]), :class => 'inputboxes' %>
```

It is storing it in the database, but in the edit view it does not show the stored value. How do I show it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
options_for_select(your_array_list, your_selected_value)
```

Comment: where is the your_array_list stored

Comment: Phases is a table in the database

Comment: It can be your example array `["RFP Stage", "Pre Contract", "Awarded", "Unsuccessful", "Completed"]` and the selected value `Phase.current_phase`. This is just an example.

Comment: ok so..
<%= f.select :phase_names, options_for_select(["RFP Stage", "Pre Contract", "Awarded", "Unsuccessful", "Completed"]), Phase.current_phase, :class => 'inputboxes' %>

Is what you saying----Not Working

Comment: Put it inside the parentheses. `([...], Phase.current_phase)`

Comment: <%= f.select :phase_names, options_for_select(["RFP Stage", "Pre Contract", "Awarded", "Unsuccessful", "Completed"], Phase.current_phase), :class => 'inputboxes' %>

Not Working

Comment: Take a look at the options_for_select documentation http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

Comment: Thanks come across this earlier but no success

Comment: Would a simply boolean with a Draft / Published work the same way or different